# How to muffle rain hitting overhanging steel eave?

Tags: roof, sound-proofing, rain

In order to stop rain soaking in through  the walls a narrow 15cm steel eave was added above a couple of windows at my place. It does the job, we no longer get any water entering the building. But, it is incredibly loud when it rains heavily. I suspect there are a couple of reasons for this: unlike a regular roof, there's nothing underneath to muffle the sound, no insulation or ceiling. Second, because it is free standing one end isn't anchored, just held up on occasional brackets. Lastly it may not actually be the direct raindrops that make it so loud, but larger drops from the same eave one floor above, so that the impact is much harder and louder than regular raindrops.

I was wondering if a foam or rubber could be glued to the under surface to muffle the sound? I've done a little searching, and most noise reduction methods seem to be focused on sky lights, or else putting a mesh above the roof to cut the speed of the drops. That might be a solution, but not as simple as gluing something underneath. But that's only my guess about what would help... Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you own or rent? If you rent, you probably need to check with the landlord before gluing anything to the metal. A layer of foam underneath will help muffle the sound, but it won't eliminate it. Some screen door mesh on a frame above it does sound like it would work better.

Comment: @FreeMan It would be something to suggest/request the body corporate do.

Comment: magnets would help by coupling mass to the resonation, thereby lowering volume. your foam idea can work too if heavy foam like dynamat. you could also magnet a diffuser to the splash zone if you're getting a drip from a single spot.

Answer (score 1):

There are self-adhesive [tapes](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B079S1TTGR) and [panels](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07B75PD8B) (links for reference only, you can find many others) that can be applied to the underside of the awnings. If you're renting or in a condo, note that removal might be tedious, requiring gentle heat, and cleanup (after peeling) with solvent.

You might apply additional aids to keep these from peeling off by themselves, such as magnets.